# Override Model.save() for FileField handled by Boto -- Django

Tags: django, django-models, boto

Because Heroku times out after 30 s., I have to upload user-submitted files directly to S3.  After I upload them to S3, I insert an entry in the database to record that I received this file.  Here's my model:

```
class UserUploadedFile(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    uid = models.ForeignKey('auth.user', editable=False, db_column='uid')
    filepath = models.FileField(storage=S3BotoStorage(bucket='whatever'), upload_to='/')
```

But because Boto is automatically invoked, when I call save() like so, Boto is invoked to handle the file:

```
file = UserUploadedFile(uid=request.user, filepath=key)
file.save()
```

(I do need filepath to be handled by Boto so I can get its URL, filesize, &c. later, so I can't turn filepath into a string.)

Anyway, I tried overriding save() like so to get around Boto:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    filepath = self.filepath
    if self.filepath:
        self.filepath = ''
    super(UserUploadedFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    self.raw('UPDATE mysite_useruploadedfile SET filepath=%s WHERE id=%d', [filepath, self.pk])
```

But I get this error:

```
'UserUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'raw'
```

I'm not sure how to call raw() in this context, clearly...

...but **my main question is whether this is the correct way to bypass the storage engine when I am writing to this table, or if there is a cleaner way to do it**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can overide the storage backend with a custom backend with an app like django-storages http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html which even supports amazon s3 once they upload you can get the url of the file easily

Comment: Is it possible to use to use django-storages without Boto?  I thought Boto was how django-storages handled an S3 backend?  I am using both currently.  (Sorry for late response -- I didn't see the notification for this.)